# How to add more providers to QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, postgresql, docker

I have built a Docker image containing QGIS.

```
FROM qgis/qgis:release-3_18

## Set environment variables
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8



RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y wget \
    bzip2 \
    ca-certificates \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git-core \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-virtualenv \
    unzip \
    software-properties-common \
    llvm \
    pdal

## Install packages to Python3
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install cython
RUN pip3 install numpy pandas geopandas psycopg2 sqlalchemy json5 sshtunnel xmltodict python-dotenv geoalchemy2 atoma rtree owslib osmnx pdal==2.2.0

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run the container, I'm able to import `qgis.core` and see the list of `QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()`.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProviderRegistry
print(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList())
```

It prints:

```
['ept', 'gdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'ogr', 'vectortile']
```

Unfortunately, it is not enough for my needs. In my python script, I use provider postgresql and WFS. I have no idea how to install/append/add these two providers so that I can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what worked for me was using command inside Docker image:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -noreset & export DISPLAY=:99
```

before running any Python script. Now every QGIS providers is available